# How to remove a couple tiles BEFORE grouting

Tags: kitchens, tile, construction, backsplash

Long story short - I installed a subway tile backsplash and 95% of it looks good, but there is a 1 foot by 1 foot area that came out wavy.

I want to remove just this small area and redo it before I grout. What’s the best way to remove these 7 or so subway tiles without affecting the ones around it?

Comment: Remove or destroy? Destroy is easy, grout or no grout. A couple of taps with a hammer turns it into a mess that you clean up with a chisel.

Comment: @Mazura - Gotcha. So you just chise it all flat and re-do?

Comment: Yeah but it might  end up worse when all is said and done.  Add a picture with  a sideview.  Maybe you should just grout it...